# fetch and retrieve data from firebase in swift

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fetch, swift4

what I am trying to do is fetching data from firebase, but the data is nil because the user did not send his data to firebase yet, so when he enter the view controller that should show his data, the compiler make error. How can I solve this error? I tride to add alert, but it's still not working.

```
  func getData(){
      ref = Database.database().reference()
      let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

          ref.child("users")
               .queryOrdered(byChild: "uid")
               .queryEqual(toValue:userID)
               .observe(.value) { (snapshot, error) in
               if error == nil{// alert} elses{

                   if let data = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                   if snapshot.exists() {

          for a in ((snapshot.value as AnyObject).allKeys)!{
          let users = data.value(forKey:a as! String) as! NSDictionary


            let address = users.value(forKey:"Address") as! NSDictionary
            self.lblAddressNickname.text = address.value(forKey:"addressNickname") as? String
         }

                           }
                       }

                   }
           }
  }
```

Comment: I want the alert give him a hint to go and adding his data, at the same time there is users how entered there data so there is no need to use the alert. I hope some one understand my question. sorry for poor english

Answer (score 0):

So as of now i understand the question that you have problem in fetching data from firebase when no data is in the firebase and then alert will come and it will redirect to a new controller?

So based on my understanding i will give answer if any problem of understanding things then reply me?

first you have to check that particular user have any data in firebase database so if there is no data then alert function will call

```
if let data == data
{

fetch_logic is here

}

else
{

let alert = UIAlertController(title:"Add Data",message:"",preferredStyle: .alert)

let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Button", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in

}
 alert.addAction(action)

 present(alert,animation:true,completion:true)

}
```